# Return and link to homepage django

Tags: python, django

I have a project in DJANGO with this structure:

```
/
|---- core
|---- client
```

In client/views.py, I have the code:

```
class ClientDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Cliente
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cliente_list')
```

Where client_list is the HTML page on client/clients that lists all clients.

In core/views.py module, I have the function:

```
def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Where "home.html" is the homepage.
My main urls.py is something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^cliente/', include('clientes.urls')),
    url(r'^about/', aboutpage),
    url(r'^$', homepage),
]
```

I need to return and make a link into client, core, and other apps to homepage. But when I try to return homepage into `client.views.ClientDelete`, the url on browser didn't redirect to home, but shows something like:

`localhost:8000/client/home` when I want back to `localhost:8000`.

What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: is linking them to the homepage instead of whatever `cliente_list` is not enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is useful to set names for urls:

```
url(r'^$', homepage, name='home')
```

So for your code you should do:

```
class ClientDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Cliente
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

if you want to be redirected to home page.
You can also use namespaces if you have different apps. So you will be able to do:

```
# redirect to home
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
# redirect to clients list
success_url = reverse_lazy('clients:list')
```

To use it you need to make following changes:

```
url(r'^cliente/', include('clients.urls', namespace='clients'))
```

and set a name for urls inside clientes.urls.

Docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs